# App crashing on startup

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

There's an app I've been trying my hands at. Whenever I run the app on my device and can't seem to figure out the problem. Here's the logcat when I run the app.`

```
11-11 22:21:01.917 2064-2064/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.android.timeforacoffee, PID: 2064
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.timeforacoffee/com.example.android.timeforacoffee.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.timeforacoffee.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.timeforacoffee-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.timeforacoffee-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2566)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.timeforacoffee.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.timeforacoffee-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.timeforacoffee-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2556)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.timeforacoffee.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.1_96dec127ae08ed7d09cd8e50d59e153fe09eff44-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_e6f2b5c2677fe7bed0a9a175ec8510d0067c0bb8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_db2fc7a0fd59eaaca41c0078cc1bf01aa7539ba6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_acf3c442cf3249ba0d4ba8de44f83da826715f04-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_9e08c46bb4202676e7061f6e8808197f4d6d80d9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.android.timeforacoffee/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_6f14fc144bd45ad6ad21cb47f6c557ceb08dcd76-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.examp
```

My Android Manifest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The XML Code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/customer_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="text"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TOPPINGS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:text="Whipped Cream"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chocolate_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chocolate"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="QUANTITY!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:onClick="decrement"
                android:text="-" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:onClick="increment"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:text="Order"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ORDER SUMMARY"
            android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: is your mainActivity in :com/example/timeforacoffee/ ?

Comment: is the activity declared in manifest?

Comment: @OmidZamani My main activity is located in com/example/android/timeforacoffee/ .

Comment: @Androidjack I have attached the Manifest file code.

Comment: @MokshVerma please, try to use absolute path instead of just .MainActivity and see what happens. So the absolute path will be com.example.android.timeforacoffee.MainActivity

Comment: Use APK Analyzer to check that your `MainActivity` class is actually in the APK in the place you think it should be. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html

Comment: post your xml code..

Comment: @minhazur it says Unresolved Class 'MainActivity'. even after typing the absolute path.

Comment: @MokshVerma please, share the code base if hosted on github.

Comment: @minhazur Not hosted on Github